# Conditional formatting colliding in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

***First condition***: Give a strike-through to the list when checkbox is True.

***Second condition***: Highlight every 3 rows for readability.

The problem is that I want the first condition to give only strikes, but it also change the background color. I don't want to change the background color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Google Sheets doesn't allow you prioritise conditional formatting statements, but you can achieve this by modifying and adding a third rule.*

#### More Information:

At the moment, you have two conditional formatting rules:

The one which colours every three rows, set on the rows of the sheet:

```
=AND(MOD(ROW() ,6)>0,MOD(ROW() ,6)<4)
```

And the one which sets the text in column B to strikeout if the respective checkbox in column A is checked, set on column B:

```
=A1:A=TRUE
```

The problem is that the strikeout rule will not ignore the other conditional rules, and so will not honour the first rule which sets the row colour.

#### Fix:

Firstly, you can keep the formula which colours the rows:

```
=AND(MOD(ROW() ,6)>0,MOD(ROW() ,6)<4)
```

Making sure that the Formatting style is *only* for the row colour.

You will then need to have two additional rules which keep both the formatting of the colour, as well as the strikeout:

The first, will affect rows `1-3`, `7-9`, `13-15` etc. For this, your formatting style should be the correct colour for rows `1-3`, *as well as* the strikeout:

```
=AND(AND(MOD(ROW(),6)>0,MOD(ROW(),6)<4),A1:A32=TRUE)
```

[image]

And the second will affect rows `4-6`, `10-12`, `16-18` etc. For this, your formatting style should be the correct colour for rows `4-6`, as well as the strikeout:

```
=AND(A1:A32=TRUE,OR(MOD(ROW(),6)=0,MOD(ROW(),6)>4))
```

[image]

#### Showcase:

[image]